# 403 Forbidden Error on Subdomain (CentOS 5.8)

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, centos, http-status-code-403

Alright, I created a subdomain in cpanel, test.xyz.com, pointed it at the /test folder, and stuck an index.php file in it and nothing else.

When I attempted to visit it, I got a `500 Internal Server Error`, Apache saying:

```
*Wed Nov 21 14:20:59 2012] [error] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] SoftException in Application.cpp:256: File "/home/username/public_html/test/index.php" is writeable by group"*
```

So I changed the permissions down to 750 (`chmod -R 750 /home/username/public_html/test`)

Then upon refresh I received a `403 Forbidden error`, with Apache reporting a:

```
*[Wed Nov 21 13:59:12 2012] [crit] [client xx.xxx.xxx.xx] (13)Permission denied: /home/username/public_html/test/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable*
```

I don't have an .htaccess file in the directory, so I attempted to put one in there, but that did not change the error message in any way.  I have searched extensively, but the only solutions I see are to adjust to various permission levels, which I have tried in various combinations.

Comment: Is the file/directory have read and execute permission for the user running apache?

Comment: ahhh, no, it wasn't.  I re-created the directory via FTP (we log in through the apache user) and it worked fine, it was only a problem when created with a different user via ssh.  Just had to chown to the appropriate user.

Thanks for the help.